# Is it possible to directly mail a uploaded binary file with GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I am using python GAE and I want to mail a file that was in user posted to server.

I could do that (I think) by first storing the file to BlobStore, then retrieving it from Blobstore, mailing and deleting it from BlobStore.

Is it possible to do it without using BlobStore?

I have this code

```
up = self.request.POST.multi['upfile']
mail.send_mail(from_address, to_address, subject, body,
              attachments=[(up.filename, up.file.read())])
```

It works fine with text files, but with binaries it reduces the content
For example, hex dumps for original png file is:

```
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
000000  89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 .PNG........IHDR
000010  00 00 00 40 00 00 00 28 08 02 00 00 00 C1 AC 6B ...@...(.......k
000020  BE 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 AE CE 1C E9 00 00 .....sRGB.......
000030  00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0B 13 00 00 0B 13 01 00 ..pHYs..........
000040  9A 9C 18 00 00 00 07 74 49 4D 45 07 DD 05 0F 11 .......tIME.....
000050  05 38 BA 66 BF EB 00 00 00 19 74 45 58 74 43 6F .8.f......tEXtCo
000060  6D 6D 65 6E 74 00 43 72 65 61 74 65 64 20 77 69 mment.Created wi
000070  74 68 20 47 49 4D 50 57 81 0E 17 00 00 00 1D 49 th GIMPW.......I
000080  44 41 54 58 C3 ED C1 01 01 00 00 00 82 20 FF AF DATX......... ..
000090  6E 48 40 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 64 1E 28 00 01 nH@........d.(..
0000A0  D2 35 20 CA 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82 .5 .....IEND.B`.
```

And hex dump for the uploaded, mailed and downloaded one is:

```
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
000000  89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0D 0A 2D 2D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D .PNG.....--=====
000010  3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 30 36 38 30 38 34 ==========068084
000020  32 39 32 39 3D 3D 2D 2D 2D 2D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 2929==----======
000030  3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 3D 30 36 38 30 38 34 32 =========0680842
000040  39 32 39 3D 3D 2D 2D 929==--
```

I am new to Python, so I maybe wrong on even basics.

Is it wrong to read file using read() if it is binary? (when I did it on filesystem it looked fine)
Or is it wrong to send binary data on GAE like I do? (is it not byte string as required?)

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine infers mime types from the file extension. Have you checked your email headers to make sure that the correct mime type is supplied with the email to ensure it is properly encoded?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments

Comment: I have the following header for the mail:
`Content-Type: multipart/mixed`
and this for the attachment:
`--===============0683392253==
Content-Type: image/png
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="a.png"

‰PNG

--===============0683392253==`